# How to protect against purge of bash history?

Tags: bash, command-history, shutdown, i3

Following the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88856/13428):

> When closing multiple bash instances at the same time, there is a
>   known race condition that may cause the history to be cleared. This
>   occurs because there is no locking used when the bash history file is
>   written.

How can I prevent against this cause of bash history purge?

I use i3wm and I think that it happens mostly when I shutdown the computer before I manually close `urxvt` terminals. The command used (via keybind) for shutdown is `systemctl poweroff`.

Comment: very similar to question <http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows>

Comment: Zsh doesn't have this bug...

Comment: @FranklinPiat Similar object(bash+history), but quite different question. I don't want to share histories between already made sessions. I just want to keep all the commands I've used at next computer start-up. Also I want to prevent of history purge.

Comment: @Giles I've just found slides "ZSH vs BASH". ZSH looks cool ^_^

Answer (score 3):

The source of the race condition is because bash only writes the history file as the shell exits. Plus it will over write the existing history file if multiple shells are running, only the last to exit will dominate the history.

So one solution is to write history out, after EVERY command. There or some negative consequences to this, such as you'll be able to up arrow history events occurring in other windows, and therefor will expose to all open shells (that you own) what commands you just ran. The most likely place this will bite you is if you are doing a repetitive set of commands, like 'up arrow N times, then hit enter' over and over again. If in a closed window a background process ends, then suddenly you'll need to pay closer attention what command is really 'up arrow N+1 times' risking running the wrong command.

To turn 'history on with every command' try adding these to you .bashrc (number of lines of history to store are just examples, you can change them for your comfort)

```
HISTFILESIZE=400000000
HISTSIZE=10000
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a"
export HISTSIZE PROMPT_COMMAND

shopt -s histappend
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but I don't want to share histories between running sessions. Would it be possible without affecting already made sessions?

Answer (score 1):

When you start bash, it will warn you if your history has been deleted (as measured by line count).  If the history has not been deleted, it will be backed up.

`~/.bashrc`

```
# backup history/warn about deleted history
if (( $(wc -l < ~/.bash_history) < 1100 ))
then
    echo "#########################"
    echo ".bash_history was cleared"
    echo "#########################"
else
    cp ~/.bash_history ~/.bash_history.back
fi
```

Comment: (1) Can you explain how this answers the question?  (2) The question is about the risks of doing asynchronous file modification without benefit of a synchronization protocol like file locking.  This answer seems to be throwing gasoline on the fire, by writing the ``.bash_history.back`` file in *every* new bash process, in a context where the user may be opening multiple new windows at the same time.

Comment: @Scott: (2) I really don't think the asker had any of that in mind.  They just want to stop losing their history. (1) While I agree this solution doesn't answer the question directly (i.e. How can this problem be prevented?), this does help mitigate the damage. As for making the problem worse, I don't see an issue.  My `.bash_history` is 100k lines and backing it up it adds 8ms to the startup time.  Even more, the race condition is caused when the bash instances are closed, not started.

Comment: @Evidlo added to my `.bashrc` thank you

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to merge in-memory history with the on-disk history, before logging out...

Note only that it does so while preserving history timestamp ordering, and command order within those timestamps.

Optionally removing unique commands (even if multi-line), and/or removing (cleaning out) simple and/or sensitive commands, according to defined perl RE's. Adjust to suit!

This is the result... https://antofthy.gitlab.io/software/history_merge.bash.txt

I source this script either 'on demand' via a shell alias 'hc' (for history clean), and from the ".bash_logout" profile, to merge/clean before exiting.

Enjoy.